# Require ip x.x.x.x not working in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4

I edited my apache2.conf (on Ubuntu) to restrict access to all except from one IP, but I still can access from other IPs. Below is my configuration:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require ip x.x.x.x
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require ip x.x.x.x
</Directory>
```

authz_core module is loaded, so is there something wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example of access restriction from IP addresses for Apache 2.4:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
      <RequireAny>
        Require ip 127.0.0.1
        Require ip ::1
        Require ip x.x.x.x
      </RequireAny>
    </IfModule> 
</Directory>
```

Don't forget to restart apache service by running this command:

```
service httpd restart
```

Also don't use `directory /` for security reasons.

Comment: I don't understand why this would have solved the problem - unless it was simply a case of forgetting to restart Apache. Sure, it's better... checking that the mod_authz_core module is loaded, and explicity stating RequireAny rather than relying on that as default behaviour... but as far as I can see, the syntax in the question should work too?

Comment: From apache 2.4 documentation: `<RequireAll> and</RequireAll> are used to enclose a group of authorization directives of which none must fail and at least one must succeed in order for the <RequireAll> directive to succeed.

If none of the directives contained within the <RequireAll> directive fails, and at least one succeeds, then the <RequireAll> directive succeeds. If none succeed and none fail, then it returns a neutral result. In all other cases, it fails.`

Comment: `RequireAll` isn't being used in the question or in the answer. You're using `RequireAny` which is the default behaviour (i.e. if you took out `<RequireAny>` and `</RequireAny>` from your answer it would make no functional difference)

Comment: "Sure, it's better... checking that the mod_authz_core module is loaded" - this isn't necessarily "better". In fact, this is probably worse. This means that if mod_authz_core is not available (or was ever disabled) then all users gain unrestricted access with no error - this is probably not desirable! The presence of an `<IfModule>` wrapper implies that the contained directives are _optional_. @DougMcLean

Comment: "Also don't use `directory /` for security reason." - Although, the OP is using the `<Directory />` container to _restrict_ all access (`AllowOverride None` / `Require all denied`), not allow it, which _is recommended_.